# How to correctly pass data from child to a parent component using the event bus?

Tags: vue.js, parent-child

I'm using a stepper, and I'm trying to move to the next step via a button click (the stepper itself is a standalone parent component (view), here's a link to said stepper: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers#stepper).
However, using the example referenced in the link above, I moved the button that takes you to the next step in a child component (a table) and I'm trying to trigger the event that does the stepping via an event bus.

The steps that I've taken so far are:

1. I created an event-bus.js file, populated it with:

   ```
   import Vue from "vue";
   export const EventBus = new Vue();
   ```

   and I have imported it in both the parent (stepper) & the child components (table with button in it)
2. I imported the child component into the parent.
3. Here's how the EventBus set-up looks in my child component:

   ```
   <v-btn
      color="#009af9"
      large
      dark
      @click="stepperPageOne()">Next</v-btn>

   data: () => ({
       e1: 0
   }),
   methods: {
      stepperPageOne() {
          EventBus.$emit("changePage", this.e1++);
          console.log(this.e1);
      }
   }
   ```
4. Here's how it looks in the parent component:

   ```
   <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > stepperCatcher()" step="1" color="#68C977">Schedule
   </v-stepper-step>

   data: () => ({
      e1: 0
   }) ,
   methods: {
       stepperCatcher() {
           EventBus.$on("changePage");
           console.log("changePage");
       }
   }
   ```

When I click the button in the child component, the event associated with it fires (I've logged it), but the stepper doesn't change steps.

When I refresh the view where the stepper is located, the event associated with it that is supposed to catch when i click the button in it's child component immediately fires twice.

Can someone help me out how to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the purpose of this:

```
:complete="e1 > stepperCatcher()"
```

and this:

```
stepperCatcher() {
  EventBus.$on("changePage");
  console.log("changePage");
}
```

`stepperCatcher()` isn't returning anything so the condition `e1 > stepperCatcher()` is nonsensical.

You're emitting the event correctly but you are not listening to it correctly.

You need to register an event listener for the event in the `created` hook of your parent component and then unregister the listener in the `destroyed` hook. Something like this:

```js
created() {
  EventBus.$on('changePage', this.handleChangePage)
},

destroyed() {
  EventBus.$off('changePage', this.handleChangePage)
},

methods: {
  handleChangePage(e1) {
    // Handle the event here
  }
}
```

See the docs for [`$on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on).

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, i'll look into it!